# Moq sub property of type enum: variable 'x' of type 'xxx' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to Mock one of the interfaces I use for testing purposes and get the error:

> *variable 'x' of type 'IMyInterface' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined*

when setting up the mock

```
var mymock = new Mock<IMyInterface>( MockBehavior.Strict );
mymock.Setup( x => x.Prop1.Prop2 ).Returns( PropTypesEnum.enumvalue );
```

- `Prop1` is also of interface type
- `Prop2` type `enum`
- There is a CoClass attribute for the interface type of `Prop1`

I'm quite new with Moq so don't know if this is because of something really simple or something really complicated.

Full error stack (some spanish there - sorry):

```
en System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Reference(ParameterExpression node, VariableStorageKind storage)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitArguments(IArgumentProvider nodes)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
   en Moq.Mock.GetTargetMock(Expression fluentExpression, Mock mock) en C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:línea 897
   en Moq.Mock.SetupGetPexProtected[T,TProperty](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Condition condition) en C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:línea 581
   en Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T1,T2,T3,TResult](Func`4 function, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3) en C:\projects\moq4\Source\PexProtector.cs:línea 75
   en Moq.Mock.SetupGet[T,TProperty](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Condition condition) en C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:línea 559
   en Moq.Mock.SetupPexProtected[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Condition condition) en C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:línea 537
   en Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T1,T2,T3,TResult](Func`4 function, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3) en C:\projects\moq4\Source\PexProtector.cs:línea 75
   en Moq.Mock.Setup[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Condition condition) en C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:línea 526
   en Moq.Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression) en C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.Generic.cs:línea 362
   en [removed my own code line]
Mensaje de Result:  System.InvalidOperationException : se hace referencia a la variable 'x' del tipo 'IMyInterface' desde el ámbito '', pero no se ha definido
```

Comment: It is an expression problem with the naming of the parameter. Rename the expression parameter. ie `mymock.Setup( _ => _.Prop1.Prop2 ).Returns( PropTypesEnum.enumvalue );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in my case the interface was defined in a separate dll. The reference to this dll had `Embed Interop Types = True` which caused the error and setting it to `false` fixed it (it was my mistake to not mention the reference).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, the problem might be with the CoClass attribute. Not familiar with this attribute myself, but it seems to be a way to bind an interface to a COM object.

Looking at the source code of the VariableBinder ([src](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/b31308b03e8bd5bf779fb80fda71f31eb959fe0b/System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/VariableBinder.cs#L221)) I find the following statement:

```
 if (definition == null) {
      throw Error.UndefinedVariable(node.Name, node.Type, CurrentLambdaName);
 }
```

The methodname and passed parameters make me believe that it is likely the location where the exception is thrown.

---

*So why is it thrown?*

My guess is that the expression compiler (somehow) cannot figure out what the actual type is you specify in your CoClass. But this would be just a wild guess.

---

You could try by referencing non-enum types on your `Prop1` interface, see if that works (might also give more info to fix it). Also check if you can instantiate the interface with the CoClass attribute (from within your test-method), to ensure it is able to find the COM object.